# Convert Rails 6 generator to make Minitest test files after being an RSpec project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, minitest

#### Summary

I am converting a Rails project from RSPec to Minitest and want my Rails project generator to create minitest test files.

---

#### In detail

I have a Rails project which I generated with skipped tests:

```
 rails new example --skip-test-unit
```

I then added RSpec (following the standard `rails generate rspec:install`). Then I thought I'd like to try minitest instead.

I made a project doppelganger and copied test directory into my rails project:

```
 rails new example  # so we have test unit now
```

While I can run minitest tests the generator does not make the files for me.

```
rails g model Contact --skip-migration

Running via Spring preloader in process 13814
      invoke  active_record
      create    app/models/contact.rb
      # no test files!
```

I have tried:

- Reading through stackoverflow - everyone is converting it into RSpec
- Stop and started Spring
- commenting out a line in application.rb `config.generators.system_tests = nil`

How can I fix this to get minitest files generated?

Answer (score 2):

I diffed a new application with my current application and application.rb's requires were very different.

#### App not generating test files

```
# rails/config/application.rb

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_mailbox/engine"
require "action_text/engine"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie" <= generator left test_unit commented out
```

#### App Generating test files

```
# rails/config/application.rb

require "rails/all"
```

I made the require statements in my non-generating app like the generating app. ran `spring stop` and ran `rails generator` which now worked.

```
rails g model Contact --skip-migration

Running via Spring preloader in process 16286
      invoke  active_record
      create    app/models/contact.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/contact_test.rb
      invoke      factory_bot
      create        test/factories/contacts.rb
```